# NodeJS and MySQL. Why the field makes an error in the query statement?

Tags: mysql, node.js

Using NodeJS and MySQL I had an error in my query statement of database fields called `user_name`.

Why `user_name` makes an error and what is the solution?

```
function get_role(callback) {
    tempCont.query('SELECT * from `users` where `user_name` = ahmed' , function (error, results) {
        if (error) callback(null);
        callback(results[0].password);
        console.log("from query = " + results[0].password);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bare keyword (`ahmed`) which should be quoted:

```
function get_role(callback) {
    tempCont.query("SELECT * from `users` where `user_name` = 'ahmed'" , function (error, results) {
        if (error) callback(null);
        callback(results[0].password);
        console.log("from query = " + results[0].password);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

function get_role(callback) {
    tempCont.query("SELECT * from `users` where `user_name` = 'ahmed'" , function (error, results) {
        if (error) callback(null);
        callback(results[0].password);
        console.log("from query = " + results[0].password);
    });
}